# Segmentation fault in boogle

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to solve boogle problem in the brute force approach. The inputs are:

The grid matrix, represented as a string, for example :'pesa'
The word, also represented as a string 'asa'.

I am writing a function to check if the word is a legal word in the matrix.

```
bool Boogle::contains(std::string grid, std::string word) const
{
    bool* isvisited=new bool[grid.length()];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<grid.length(); i++)
    {
        *(isvisited+i)=false;
    }

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<grid.length(); i++)
    {
        // Recursive approach
        if (grid[i]==word[0])
            if (checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, i, 0))
                return true;    
    }
    return false;
}

bool Boogle::checkqueue(const string &grid, const string &word, bool* const &isvisited, unsigned int grid_index, unsigned int count) const
{   
    int matsize=int(sqrt(grid.length()));
    cout<<"\nCurrently at the index "<<grid_index<<"\n";
    isvisited[grid_index]=true;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<grid.length(); i++)
    {
        cout <<isvisited[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    if (count==word.length()-1)
    {
        cout << " reach the end of word\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        count ++;
        cout << "Recursive call on WORD: "<<word<<"  " <<count<<" "<<word[count]<<"\n";

        // non diagonal
        if ((grid_index<grid.length()) && (isvisited[grid_index+1]==false) && (grid[grid_index+1]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index+1, count);

        else if ((grid_index>0)&& (isvisited[grid_index-1]==false)  && (grid[grid_index-1]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index-1, count);

        else if (((grid_index+matsize)<grid.length())&& (isvisited[grid_index+matsize]==false)  && (grid[grid_index+matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index+1, count);

        else if (((grid_index-matsize)<grid.length())&& (isvisited[grid_index-matsize]==false)  && (grid[grid_index-matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index+1, count);

        // diagonal
        else if ((grid_index-1-matsize>0)&& (isvisited[grid_index-1-matsize]==false)  && (grid[grid_index-1-matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index-1-matsize, count);

        else if ((grid_index+1-matsize>0) && (isvisited[grid_index+1-matsize]==false) && (grid[grid_index+1-matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index+1-matsize, count);

        else if ((grid_index+1+matsize<grid.length())&& (isvisited[grid_index+1+matsize]==false)  && (grid[grid_index+1+matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index+1+matsize, count);

        else if ((grid_index-1+matsize<grid.length())&& (isvisited[grid_index-1+matsize]==false)  && (grid[grid_index-1+matsize]==word[count]))
            return checkqueue(grid, word, isvisited, grid_index-1+matsize, count);
        else
        {
            // cout<<"No possible neighbor\n";
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

If i run boogle.contains("pesa","as") it works great. But if that's an illegal word such as "asa", it returns segmentation fault. Where does that come from?

```
./Boogle.exe 
.
Currently at the index 3
0 0 0 1 
Recursive call on WORD: asa  1 s

Currently at the index 2
0 0 1 1 
Recursive call on WORD: asa  2 a
Segmentation fault: 11
```

P/S: This is correct running when the word is valid (boogle.contains("pesa","esp"))

```
Currently at the index 1
0 1 0 0 
Recursive call on WORD: esp  1 s

Currently at the index 2
0 1 1 0 
Recursive call on WORD: esp  2 p

Currently at the index 3
0 1 1 1 
 reach the end of word



OK (1 tests)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to display `cout << grid_index-1-matsize << endl;` before your condition list. You will see that a buffer underflow happens since `grid_index` is unsigned.

For that reason, you condition `(grid_index-matsize)<grid.length()` is true since `grid_index` is way over `grid.length()`.

You have to change the signature of the function `checkqueue` into

```
bool Boogle::checkqueue(const string &grid, const string &word, bool* const &isvisited, int grid_index, unsigned int count) const
```

Comment: Actually grid_index is for the matrix. Variable count is for the word, and I have the boundary checking here: grid_index<grid.length()

Comment: @DzungNguyen Ok, I took the time and looked carefully to your code, my answer should be more suitable now ;)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have had trouble with this bug for a week!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing signed and unsigned arithmetic. `matsize` is `int` and `grid_index` is `unsigned int`. Your comparison to `>0` is not working, since the result is alway unsigned and thus never negative.

btw, you probably want `>=0` after you fix the signed/unsigned mismatch.

Comment: I turn on -Wall on g++, and it does not show up any warning about that. I did change to unsigned but it does not help. The problem is when it can't find the next recursion (no valid move) then it has segmentation problem.

Comment: I think the warning would happen if you had `>= 0`, since `(unsigned int) >=0` is always true so it is meaningless. `(unsigned int)>0` could possibly be true if it was zero, so that is why you didn't get a warning.